# Can I turn on WiFi-Direct from code? on API-16 (Android 4.2.2)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, wifi-direct

I am developing an application with NFC and wifi direct. I get the MAC address using NFC and the Wifi Direct to transfer data. I call discoverpeers() and could get success. But there is no callback `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION`, the callback comes only when I go to settings and the select wifidirect.

This was discussed in the other question

[Can I turn on WiFi-Direct from code? on Android API-14 (ICS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571566/can-i-turn-on-wifi-direct-from-code-on-android-api-14-ics)

"I'd like to add that WiFi direct on JB and above (at least on AOSP) is not active all the time - it only appears to be. If you look at listeners for WiFi direct, it turns itself off after some time. It turns itself back on if you open the wifi direct menu, however. You might have to have the host do a peer search or initialize itself in order to be able to be found. Likely a battery saving trick. I have also found that it's blocking, since as it accepts a connection, the entire system will lock up and fail to connect sometimes. (The system invitation) – Mgamerz "

Can anyone suggest the solution for the problem `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` callback is not got and can get only when manually go to settings->wifi->tap on wifidirect

I used two devices Samsung galaxy nexus and nexus 7 both running on 4.2.2

Answer (score 4):

There is no available API to enable `wifiP2P` but you can invoke method **"enableP2p"** from android settings 4.0.1

```
WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
Channel channel = manager.initialize(getActivity(), getActivity().getMainLooper(), null);

try {
            Method method1 = manager.getClass().getMethod("enableP2p", Channel.class);
            method1.invoke(manager, channel);
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "method found",
             //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "method did not found",
                 //   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

To disable `wifiP2P` use this method

```
Method method1 = manager.getClass().getMethod("disableP2p", Channel.class);
```

Comment: on my LG P769 (android 4.1.2), "method is not found". though manager and channel are not null. Does my phone support wifi direct?

Answer (score 1):

Not from code. The user has to. That's why the demo has the link to wifi settings in the action bar.

When you call   `manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()` 
define `onFailure` and look at the `reasonCode`. If it's 0, then either the Wifi or WiFi direct is off.

If you look at the WiFi Direct demo app, the `WifiDirectBroadcast Reciever`, this piece of code looks at whether p2p is enabled specifically

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
            activity.resetData();

        }
```

Then when discover peers is called it looks at the variable set by `setIsWifiP2pEnabled`

Comment: @jabaldonedo in 4.2.2 there is no option to enable in settings. My problem is the callback WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION comes only if i go to settings select wifidirect        Note: Selecting is not turning ON

Answer (score 1):

thanks user3093354. to continue with your solution, in order to disable the p2p you have to invoke:

```
Method method1 = manager.getClass().getMethod("disableP2p", Channel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this it may be help you

WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);        //True - to enable WIFI connectivity .
                                         //False -disable WIFI connectivity.

//add this permissions in Manifest file :


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am looking for wifi direct

Comment: @Mgamerz  i have linked to post where you have commented

Answer (score 0):

You can load the wifi driver from a command prompt with the desired concurrency level if you are rooted:

/system/bin/insmod /system/lib/modules/wlan.ko con_mode=3

These are the values:
`typedef enum 
{ 
    VOS_STA_MODE=0,
    VOS_STA_SAP_MODE=1,
    VOS_P2P_CLIENT_MODE,
    VOS_P2P_GO_MODE,
    VOS_MONITOR_MODE,
    VOS_FTM_MODE = 5,
    VOS_IBSS_MODE,
    VOS_P2P_DEVICE_MODE,
    VOS_MAX_NO_OF_MODE
} tVOS_CON_MODE;`

This is for an Atheros card.