# WiFi Direct status

Tags: android, p2p, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager

Is it possible to specifically check that whether WiFi Direct is On or Off ?
I wrote a code which can only update about the wifi status that whether it is connected or not,no matter it is Access point or WiFi Direct

```
  ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {

                    }
                    if (!mWifi.isConnected()) {


                    }
```

I want to specifically check about the WiFi Direct status.Please help.

Comment: Maybe this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571566/can-i-turn-on-wifi-direct-from-code-on-android-api-14-ics can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. You use call this [WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) to check if it is enabled or disabled. Some sample code is below:

First, you need a broadcast reciever:

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private Channel mChannel;
    private MyWiFiActivity mActivity;

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
        MyWifiActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on the `OnRecieve` part of your code for the broadcast reciever, you have this code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Boolean isEnabled;
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            isEnabled = true;
        } else {
            isEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i enable the wifi adapter using `WifiP2PManager` when app starts?