# Android: How to check if device is connected to another device via WiFi - Direct?

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I was wondering if there is a way, similar to checking if there is a WiFi connection established.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
// Do whatever
}
```

But with WiFi p2p?

My application connects to a sensor via WiFi-Direct. If the user has not connected to the sensor, a textView should appear saying "You are not connected to a sensor". Currently this only works if the user starts the WiFi Direct activity, which registers a Broadcast Receiver which checks if the device is connected to something via WiFi p2p. But I want to know this without having to start my WiFi Direct activity. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034736/wifi-direct-status) one out. It's a really nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkWifiOnAndConnected() {

            WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) { // WiFi adapter is ON
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
                 connected_wifi=wifiInfo.getSSID();
            }
            else {
               // Utill.showCenteredToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.str_wifi_on));
            }
        }


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Is this really for WiFi Direct? Is this not just for regular WiFi connection?

Comment: Please check its working for me . its for wifi connection but it may work with wifi direct.

Comment: I will check, it probably works but the problem I think will be that it will not display the textView if it is connected to a router via WiFi when NOT connected via WiFi Direct to sensor.

Comment: For me, this only tells me if my WiFi is enabled or not. So it does not work for me unfortunately, thank you for the help.