# Android check Wi-Fi Direct is activated

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

How to check that Wi-Fi Direct is activated on a device?

I've tried to check Wi-Fi in the following way:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
return wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
```

but there are devices which don't support simultaneous Wi-Fi and Wi-Fi Direct (Huawei Honor 4C, it shuts down Wi-Fi, when you activate Wi-Fi Direct), so this way doesn't work.

Listening to `WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` in `BroadcastReceiver` like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034736/wifi-direct-status) isn't acceptable too, because it will be triggered only when I start some action with Wi-Fi Direct (like discovering), but I need to check its status before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi Direct status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034736/wifi-direct-status)

Comment: Check it out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533616/is-it-possible-to-connect-two-or-more-wifi-direct-groups?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533616/is-it-possible-to-connect-two-or-more-wifi-direct-groups?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver like this:

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel) {
    super();
    this.mManager = manager;
    this.mChannel = channel;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Boolean isEnabled;

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // check if Wi-Fi is enabled 
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            isEnabled = true;
        } else {
            isEnabled = false;
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // get list of peers by WifiP2pManager.requestPeers()
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to new connections 
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // on device's wifi state changes
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a code from an answer, I linked in question. It is not acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ConnectivityManager to get the state of the Wi-Fi.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
        // Do whatever
    }
```

Please Check you permission in manifest ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE && INTERNET.

Comment: This is about Wi-Fi, not Wi-Fi Direct. And this method is deprecated.