# Are Wi-Fi Direct and Wi-Fi P2P the same?

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Maybe this is a stupid question but..

Are Wi-Fi Direct and Wi-Fi P2P the same thing?

And I mean, the EXACTLY same thing?

I'm getting really confused with this two.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. But your answer can be found in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page for "Wi-Fi Direct".

Comment: Spanish speaker here. Wikipedia page for "Wi-Fi Direct" in spanish decided to hide that information... Thank you btw

Comment: Yes, Wi-Fi direct == Wifi P2p.

"Android's Wi-Fi P2P framework complies with the Wi-Fi Alliance's Wi-Fi Direct™ certification program" (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#transferring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wifi Direct is a technology for peer to peer connections and is very different from wifi. Wi-Fi Direct, initially called Wi-Fi P2P, is a Wi-Fi standard enabling devices to easily connect with each other without requiring a wireless access point.It is usable for everything from internet browsing to file transfer

Wifi Direct is not same as wifi . On Jelly Bean and above, when you try to use the WifiP2pManager API, WiFi-Direct is automatically enabled (as long as WiFi is on). Wifi can be switched on by calling:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

For ICS refer to this [Can I turn on WiFi-Direct from code? on Android API-14 (ICS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571566/can-i-turn-on-wifi-direct-from-code-on-android-api-14-ics)
This is the main reason to get confused between the two.

Comment: OP did not ask "if Wi-Fi Direct is same as Wi-Fi or not" which you have answered for, instead OP asked "if Wi-Fi Direct is same as Wi-Fi P2P or not".