# Wireless (Wifi) Chat Application

Tags: android, wifi, chat, p2p

I am a fellow Android developer and want to develop a similar app like Firechat for educational purposes

I just want to know what kind of packages and techniques I need to learn to develop a app like this

App Features :
I Need to discover the phones which Have wifi direct and my App on 
Next I need to be able to send messages and start device to device communication 
and If the device I want to connect is not in range ,The message should Hop from one device to another till the destination is reached 
I think It can done by creating a mesh network

I have went through similar techonlogies like serval/Firechat/Opengarden ,But I am not being able to comprehend it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For being able to connect devices for peer to peer connection you have the following options:

**1. Wifi Direct**

**2. Bluetooth**

**3. Wifi Hotspot**

Here is a basic tutorial on how to build a chat over wifi direct
**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html**

And for bluetooth
**http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html**

You can also import these sample projects in eclipse by:

1 **For WifiDirect** -
Go to New -> Android Sample Project -> Choose API level 16  (Android 4.1.2)-> WifiDirectDemo

2  **For Bluetooth**  -
Go to New -> Android Sample Project -> Choose API level 16  (Android 4.1.2)> BluetoothChat

Comment: Is the wifi-direct same as wifi ? I mean if a person B just turns on his wifi ,Could Person A detect his phone ?

Comment: Wifi Direct is not same as wifi .

On Jelly Bean and above, when you try to use the WifiP2pManager API, WiFi-Direct is automatically enabled (as long as WiFi is on).
Wifi can be switched on by calling

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
For ICS refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571566/can-i-turn-on-wifi-direct-from-code-on-android-api-14-ics

Comment: After wifi Direct is on , for A to see B and vice versa both devices should be discoverable . To be discoverable both devices should call 
 WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
And Then Call 
manager.discoverPeers(channel, listener)
This makes both devices discoverable and see each other .
Mark my answer as correct if satisfied

Comment: If one device name B minimizes the app, after calling WIFI_P2P_SERVICE , Will it still be discover-able by other devices like A who has the app running .?
and Can I know how to transfer strings from both Client to Server and server to client once the connection is set up ?

Comment: In any situation if discovery ends you get a system broadcast 
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION(You need to register for this intent)
You can get the state of discovery  as intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_DISCOVERY_STATE)
IF discovery has stopped you  can call l manager.discoverPeers(channel, listener)  to make discovery active again .

Comment: For a 2 directional transfer try this 
https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo
Please upvote my comments and answer .
Thanks