# how to make a smart home application through a control access?

Tags: android, devexpress

I would like to control more than 1 roller shutter via my specifique application using wifi. First question, the smart home controler are they working just with the application designed by the company or any application (designed by me) can contol it second question,to design my smart home application to control this controler what should i do????

Comment: I'd first research if your smart home controller offers an API, through which you can invoke commands. If they don't, I'd next see if they offer [IFTTT compatibility](https://ifttt.com/), which would still allow you to issue commands to it (albeit at a delay and with the dependency on the IFTTT service). Your second question is far too general to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can control home appliances using your smartphone via GSM, Bluetooth, Wifi etc. In case of Wifi, it can be done by socket program that connects to common wifi module and connects the smartphone and device to that wifi module to make host IP address same and send data through that. For details check with peer to peer connection and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487973/wireless-wifi-chat-application)